Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file transfer learning in keras
I'm new to convolutional neural network and machine learning in general, so sorry in advance if my question is really straighforward, but I have searched for a while without getting a solution to fix it. For a semantic segmentation task, I am pre-training a U-Net model of 4 convolution blocks in keras with a dataset whose patches have input_shape = (128,128,3). Then, I need to train this same model, but with a new dataset (input_shape=(128,128,5)). So far, I think I've managed to apply the convolution necessary for the U-Net model to accept tensors from 5 channels. I've saved the model with the weights in an h5 file. However, I got the error "keras load_weights() ValueError: Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. Model expected 4 layers, found 23 saved layers" at the line indicate in bold in my second code block.
I have already searched in the keras litterature and looked in other related questions here in stack overflow, but they dosn't fully answer my question.
After using the model.summary() method, I found out that when training the new model using the pre-trained model weights, an adapted input convolution layer and the output layer, I end up with a model of just 4 layers (the input layers, the pre-trained model as a single layer and the output layer.
Here my transfer learning model code:
pretrained_unet = load_model(".\projects\unet_v2.h5")
#freezing before the layer with the same input size
pretrained_unet = freeze_up_to(pretrained_unet, "dropout_5")

## Create a new input layer for the Unet
input_unet = Input(shape=(128, 128, 5))
input_layer = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape= (128,128,5))

# Convert 5-channel input to 3-channel input
filtered_unet_input = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='relu')(input_unet)
filtered_unet_input = pretrained_unet(filtered_unet_input)
#filtered_unet_input = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_unet[:,:,:3])
# Combine the UNET head and Unet
combined_output = Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(filtered_unet_input)
combined_model = keras.Model(input_unet,combined_output)
#combined_output = pretrained_unet(filtered_unet_input)

combined_model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 128, 128, 5)]     0

 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 3)       18

 UNet (Functional)           (None, 128, 128, 2)       8557570

 dense (Dense)               (None, 128, 128, 2)      

 6

=================================================================
Total params: 8,557,594
Trainable params: 110,874
Non-trainable params: 8,446,720


But my pretrained model has 23 layers. So there's a mismatch between the number of layers and the weights can't be correctly assigned. Here my code for the pretrained model:
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, TensorBoard
from keras.models import load_model, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D

# Visualization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# Working with arrays
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

# External files with functions to load the dataset,
# create a CNN model, and a data generator.
from importlib import reload
import utils
import models
import data_generator
from data_generator import DataGenerator

reload(utils)
reload(models)
reload(data_generator)

from utils import *
from models import *
from data_generator import *


# Module to track model's metrics
import wandb
import random

def fix_gpu():
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    session = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession(config=config)


fix_gpu()

PROJECT_DIR = "."  # os.getcwd()
SEED = 42
color2index = {(0, 0, 0): 0,
               (255, 255, 255): 1
               }

n_classes = len(color2index)

BATCH_SIZE = 8
PATCH_SIZE = 128
STEP_SIZE = 128
EPOCHS = 7

#define the function to freeze desired layers of the UNET model
def freeze_up_to(model, freeze_layer_name):
  """Function to freeze some layers of the model

  Args:
      model (keras.Model): a keras.Model
      freeze_layer_name (str): layer name of "model". All layers up to this layer will be freezed.

  Returns:
      keras.Model: a keras.Model with some layers freezed.
  """
  # Getting layer number based on layer name
  for id_layer, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    if layer.name == freeze_layer_name:
      layer_number = id_layer
      break

  # Froze layers
  for layer in model.layers[:layer_number]:
    layer.trainable = False

  return model

# Path to the dataset folder
DATA_PATH = join("./projects", "data/train")
print(DATA_PATH)
list_images, list_masks = read_dataset(DATA_PATH)

splits = train_val_test_dataset(list_images,
                                list_masks,
                                val_size=0.25,
                                seed=SEED)
#data generation of the train dataset (images and masks)
data_gen_train = DataGenerator(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                               patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
                               step_size=STEP_SIZE,
                               list_images=splits["images_train"],
                               list_masks=splits["masks_train"],
                               n_classes=n_classes,
                               colormap_gt=color2index
                               )
#data generation of the validation dataset (images and masks)
data_gen_val = DataGenerator(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                             patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
                             step_size=STEP_SIZE,
                             list_images=splits["images_val"],
                             list_masks=splits["masks_val"],
                             n_classes=n_classes,
                             colormap_gt=color2index
                             )

print("Number of patches for training: {}".format(len(data_gen_train) * BATCH_SIZE))
print("\nNumber of patches for validation: {}".format(len(data_gen_val) * BATCH_SIZE))

a, b = data_gen_train[0]
imgs, labels = data_gen_train[0]

show_batch(imgs, labels, color2index)

unet = get_unet(img_size=PATCH_SIZE,
                n_classes=n_classes)

unet.summary()

# Checkpoint
autosave = ModelCheckpoint("./projects/unet_v2.h5",
                           mode="max",
                           save_best_only=True,
                           monitor="val_iou",
                           verbose=1)

# Early stopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_iou',
                               patience=30,
                               verbose=1,
                               mode='max')

# Train the UNET model
unet.fit(
    data_gen_train,
    validation_data=data_gen_val,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[autosave, early_stopping]
)

# Save the trained UNET model
unet.save("./unet_v2.h5")

# Load the pretrained UNET model
pretrained_unet = load_model("./projects/unet_v2.h5")

#freezing before the layer with the same input size
pretrained_unet = freeze_up_to(pretrained_unet, "dropout_5")

## Create a new input layer for the Unet
input_unet = Input(shape=(128, 128, 5))
input_layer = Conv2D(3, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape= (128,128,5))

# Convert 5-channel input to 3-channel input
filtered_unet_input = Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='relu')(input_unet)
filtered_unet_input = pretrained_unet(filtered_unet_input)

# Combine the UNET head and Unet
combined_output = Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(filtered_unet_input)
combined_model = keras.Model(input_unet,combined_output)


# Path to the new dataset folder
NEW_DATA_PATH = join("/projects", "data/DOP")  
new_list_images, new_list_masks = read_dataset(NEW_DATA_PATH)

new_splits = train_val_test_dataset(new_list_images, new_list_masks, val_size=0.25, seed=SEED)

# Prepare data generators for the new dataset
data_gen_new_train = DataGenerator(
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
    step_size=STEP_SIZE,
    list_images=new_splits["images_train"],
    list_masks=new_splits["masks_train"],
    n_classes=n_classes,
    colormap_gt=color2index
)

data_gen_new_val = DataGenerator(
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
    step_size=STEP_SIZE,
    list_images=new_splits["images_val"],
    list_masks=new_splits["masks_val"],
    n_classes=n_classes,
    colormap_gt=color2index
)

combined_model.compile(optimizer= Adam(),
                loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                metrics=["accuracy", 
                         keras.metrics.OneHotMeanIoU(num_classes=n_classes, 
                                       name="iou")])
# Fine-tune the combined model
combined_model.fit(
    data_gen_new_train,
    validation_data=data_gen_new_val,
    epochs=8,  # You may want to use fewer epochs for fine-tuning
    callbacks=[autosave, early_stopping]
)

#Loading the weights of the trained model.
****#I get the error in this line: **
combined_model.load_weights("unet_v2.h5")**

# Evaluate the model on test data
data_gen_test = DataGenerator(
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    patch_size=PATCH_SIZE,
    step_size=STEP_SIZE,
    list_images=new_splits["images_test"],
    list_masks=new_splits["masks_test"],
    n_classes=n_classes,
    colormap_gt=color2index
)

scores_train = combined_model.evaluate(data_gen_new_train, verbose=0)
scores_val = combined_model.evaluate(data_gen_new_val, verbose=0)
scores_test = combined_model.evaluate(data_gen_test, verbose=0)


If needed, this is the method of the class Models that define the architecture of the U-Net model:
def get_unet(img_size, n_classes):
  """Function to create a U-Net architecture

  Args:
      img_size (int): size of the input image
      n_classes (int): number of classes

  Returns:
      keras.Model: a keras model created using
        the functional API
  """
  # Input
  input = Input(shape=(img_size,img_size,3))
  # Downsampling
  f1,p1 = downsampling(input, 64, times=2)
  f2,p2 = downsampling(p1, 128, times=2)
  f3,p3 = downsampling(p2, 256, times=2)
  # Bottleneck
  blottleneck = conv_block(p3, 512, times=2)
  #Upsampling
  u7 = upsampling(blottleneck, 256, layer_concat=f3)
  u8 = upsampling(u7, 128, layer_concat=f2)
  u9 = upsampling(u8, 64, layer_concat=f1)
  # Output
  output = Conv2D(filters=n_classes,
                  kernel_size=1,
                  padding="same",
                  activation="softmax")(u9)
  model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=output, name="UNet")

  model.compile(optimizer= Adam(),
                loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                metrics=["accuracy", 
                         keras.metrics.OneHotMeanIoU(num_classes=n_classes, 
                                       name="iou")])

  return model

Do you know of an alternative for loading the model not as a single layer, but as all its constituent layers? And the same for the weights? Or maybe it's the way I am building the new model from the pre-trained one. If anybody could give me some guidance, I will really appreciate it.
